# How do I get add-ins to communicate with each other?

Tags: vb.net, dll, add-in

I am developing two addins for Autodesk Inventor (iMateEditor.dll and Addin2.dll) and I want Addin2 to access classes and events from iMateEditor.dll.

I got it to work by following the steps outline in the [Microsoft Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/assemblies-gac/how-to-share-an-assembly-with-other-applications#sharing-an-assembly). However, a new problem emerged which is that in order to debug the iMateEditor.dll, I have to remove it from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). However, once I do that, Addin2 can no longer reference iMateEditor. So my question is, is there another way to have Addin2 reference iMateEditor without having to remove iMateEditor from the GAC to debug it?

Maybe there a way to embed the iMateEditor library into Addin2 whenever I build Addin2?

Comment: Add the iMateEditor project, inside the Addin2 solution, then Add Reference and choose "Solution" and iMateEditor should be in the list?

Comment: How do you add the iMateEditor project to the Addin2 project? I've referenced the iMateEditor.dll from within the Addin2 project but if I don't add the iMateEditor to the GAC then on runtime, the Addin2 will give an error saying it can't find the iMateEditor.dll

Comment: You add the imateeditor *project* to the addin2 *solution* - right click the addin2 SOLUTION, choose add existing..project, pick the inateeditor project, then add a reference to it

Comment: So I added the project to the Addin2 solution and then went Add Reference > Projects> Solution > iMateEditor and it seems that Addin2 still can't find the reference during runtime. The reference path in this window is ...\source\repos\iMateEditor\iMateEditor.vbproj. However, when I click the iMateEditor reference in the solution explorer, the path in the properties show ...\Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\iMateEditor.dll. Which is the location where the addin is being complied to for Autodesk Inventor to reference.

Comment: Is `Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\iMateEditor.dll` The output location of the imate project? What is the value of the CopyLocal on the reference to imate in addin2?

Comment: `Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ ` is the compile location for both the Addin2 and iMateEditor. It's the location that Autodesk Inventor looks at for custom addins. The CopyLocal property was orginially set to true but even after setting it to false the Addin2 still won't load.... but the iMateEditor does

Comment: What does "won't load" mean? Can you give more detail when you're explaining it?

Comment: The error I receive is `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'iMateEditor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=611f36f8c823861e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'` Then, Autodesk Inventor stops loading Addin2. However, iMateEditor is loaded and even if I try to manually load Addin2 again through the Inventor application, it still produces this error... unless I add the iMateEditor to the GAC.